# How do you manage two users with the same name in AD?

Tags: active-directory, user-management

I have two users on the network.
One is John Smith. The other John Smith Jr.

How do you as a sys admin set these two users up so they do not conflict in AD(active directory) and or FileMaker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make sure they have different usernames, and you'll be fine. The First/Last name values aren't used for authentication purposes.

Does your filemaker instance authenticate off of Active Directory? If so, the your problem is solved. If not, like AD, just give them unique usernames.

Comment: What is meant by "user name"? AD complains if the "Full name" property is the same, even if the "User logon name" is different. (ok, well, in the same OU I mean. I guess you are saying to keep them in separate OUs or something.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above it is not true. You need to have a different Name or Surname besides different account, or else it will not allow you to create a second user with the same Name and Surname.